# Search For a match inside sqlite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I Created a table that contain id , name , and birthday. I would like to call a function with a name inside of it and search for any row that contain the same name.

```
public StatsitcsHelper GetDateInfo(String name) {
    StatsitcsHelper statsitcsHelper = new StatsitcsHelper ();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase ();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery ("select nameC from " + TABLE_PROGGRES +
            " WHERE = ?", new String[] {name}, null);


    cursor.moveToFirst ();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount () > 0 && !cursor.isAfterLast ()) {
        // i want the name of the user here
        statsitcsHelper.mID = Integer.parseInt (cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex ("PID")));
        statsitcsHelper.mName = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex ("nameC"));
        statsitcsHelper.mbirthday = Integer.parseInt (cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex ("birthdayC")));
        cursor.moveToNext ();
    }
    db.close ();
    cursor.close ();
    return statsitcsHelper;

}
```

and calling it like this.

```
databaseHelper.GetDateInfo("Jhon");
```

The problem is values keep returning as zeros.

I Keep getting this ERROR.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
```

I Beleive it doest Consider Checking i just assign Textview to display whatisnde StatsitcsHelper

```
 NAME_Text.setText(statsitcsHelper.mName);
```

it shows Zero

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. First, you need one small change to your SQL query:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query ("select nameC from " + TABLE_PROGGRES +
    " WHERE nameC = ?", new String[] {name}, null);
```

You must specify which column to compare in the WHERE clause. The SELECT clause only determines which columns are returned. The WHERE clause does not automatically use the column specified in the SELECT because you can compare against any columns you want, even if they are not returned.

Second, you should check if `cursor` is `null` before you use it. This means that you should do something like

```
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // ...
}
```

Next, you should close the cursor before you close the entire database:

```
cursor.close ();
db.close ();
```

One final note, I believe you mean `StatisticsHelper`.

Comment: thank you @Code-Apprenticewhen For replaying.  using query i get Cannot resolve method 'query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], null)); . Also i attached a log to to check the values inside the if statement, its Never been called which make me wonder why

Comment: @AhmadMeer My mistake. `rawQuery()` is correct after all. I was just double-checking that.

Comment: @AhmadMeer Please edit your question to show the values you are checking.

Answer (score 1):

I found that i need to let the Cursor like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery ("select * from " + TABLE_PROGGRES +
        " WHERE nameC  = ?", new String[] {name}, null);
```

Because inside the if statement i keep assigning columns to values and i need to select them with the cursor.

Comment: `SELECT *` queries all columns. You can also specify a list of specific columns if you wish such as `SELECT PID, nameC, birthdayC`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of the rawQuery you can also use the assisted approach:

```
db.query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

In your case it would be

```
db.query("TABLE_PROGGRES",new String[]{"id_column","nameC","birthday_column"},"nameC",new String[]{name},null,null,null);
```

and you might want to rename TABLE_PROGGRES to TABLE_PROGRESS